# VBA error saving file tabs as individual files in a new folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which hardcodes a file & saves specific tabs as seperate files in a new sub folder. The macro was working fine a few weeks back but now it shows errors. Code below.

Error is intially when calling create_folder sub. Error Run time error 52 - Bad file name or number. If comment out, error occurs ActiveWorkbook.Save, file not saved.

```
Sub ExportSheets()
 
    Const SheetNameList As String = "Customer Support,HR,Operations,R&D,Sales" ' commas no spaces!

    Dim SheetNames() As String: SheetNames = Split(SheetNameList, ",")
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    Dim BaseName As String
    BaseName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 5)
    Dim sh As Object
    Dim FilePath As String

    'Create departmental reporting folder    
'   Call Create_Folder

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
    ActiveWorkbook.Save    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    'loop through sheets and set the used range to values
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        sh.Cells.Copy
        sh.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
   '     .Value = .Value
    'End With
'Next sh
    
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNames)
        sh.Copy
        FilePath = FolderPath & "\" & "Departmental Reporting" & "\" & sh.Name & " OPEX Spend 2024" & ".xlsx"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        Workbooks(Workbooks.Count).SaveAs Filename:=FilePath
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    
    MsgBox "Sheets exported.", vbInformation

End Sub

Sub Create_Folder()

    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim NewFldr As String
    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    
    FolderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    NewFldr = "Departmental Reporting"
    
    FSO.CreateFolder (FolderPath & "\" & NewFldr)
End Sub
```

The outcome & what is expected is as above

Comment: Are you working on a local/network drive, or on SharePoint/OneDrive?

Comment: @Tim file is on a local drive

Comment: If you `Debug.Print FolderPath & "\" & NewFldr` does it look like a valid path?

Comment: Apologies seems like it's on SharePoint & once I changed to & "/" the file path read fine

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out